# Event when a web page gets focused

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, google-reader

Google Reader has a nice feature that when you switch to the web page from a different web page (giving the page focus) it will show you the updates there were accumulated while the page was unfocused.
**Quick question #1**: How do they do that?

I figure that they might be binding to the mouse move events + keyboard events since I don't know any out of the box event that gives you that ability.

Googling for that is a nightmare (focus, tab, web page, user).

**Quick question #2**: Is there some package out there that gives me that ability?

I'm putting the jQuery tag as a beacon for all the web developers ninjas out there, but I don't really care about the framework (as long as its Javascript)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try using jQuery's [`focus`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [`blur`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) functions:

```js
$(window).focus(function() {
   console.log('welcome (back)');
});

$(window).blur(function() {
   console.log('bye bye');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click in and out of this frame to test the focus and blur functions.
```

Comment: jquery focus doesn't act like hover(function(), function()) (which is a shame), I needed to bind to the blur event for "focusOut"

Comment: Aight lol. Ofc you're right. My mistake, I switched the two. It should act like you said though :) Would be a nice feature. Thanks for improving it and accepting it :).

Answer (score 7):

[The opposite of focus is blur.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event)

```js
// Use document.body, as "document" alone makes the snippet demo effective.
document.addEventListener("focus", function(){
  console.log("Page in focus")
})

document.addEventListener("blur", function(){
  console.log("Page out of focus")
})
```

Comment: It works well for `window`, but not for `document`. Mistake in the answer maybe?

Comment: Definitely, it has to be `document.body`. But as i saw, using "document" alone makes the snippet running in the demo, by clicking outside/inside the frame.

Answer (score 5):

Use `focusin` (focus) and `focusout` (blur) on the `document` object:

```
$(document).bind('focus', function() {
   console.log('welcome (back)');
}).bind('blur', function() {
   console.log('bye bye');
});
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to be notified every time any field on the page receives focus. Just when you switch to a page.

Answer (score 5):

I tested in FF and `document.onfocus` is called when I switch to that window.

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between the focus/blur events discussed by other answers, and the actual Visibility API.  The best resource for this is the docs at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API